# adding one more level to a hierarchical multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, tree, hierarchical-data

Update:

Here's a flat array fetched from mysql. I use a closure table to store hierarchical relationship:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => Intel
            [id] => 53
            [name] => CPU 1978
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
             [brand] => Asus
             [id] => 537
             [name] => CPU 1999
             [parent_id] => 53
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
             [brand] => HTC
             [id] => 538
             [name] => CPU 1998
             [parent_id] => 53
        )
)
```

I have some data showing what ancient products the new products are based upon. I'm using the following code to convert a flat array into a hierarchical,multi-dimensional array:

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
 $branch = array();

 foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
        $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
        if ($children) {
            $element['children'] = $children;
        }
        $branch[] = $element;
    }
 }

 return $branch;
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => Intel
            [id] => 53
            [name] => CPU 1978
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [brand] => Asus
                            [id] => 537
                            [name] => CPU 1999
                            [parent_id] => 53
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [brand] => HTC
                            [id] => 538
                            [name] => CPU 1998
                            [parent_id] => 53
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to reorganize the tree by adding a new key `brands` to the first level and extract the children's brands as a second level's array keys, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => Intel
            [id] => 53
            [name] => CPU 1978
            [parent_id] => 0
            [brands]=> Array
                    (
                      [Asus]=> Array
                           (
                             [0] => Array
                             (
                               [id] => 537
                               [name] => CPU 1999
                               [parent_id] => 53
                             )
                           )

                      [HTC] => Array
                          (
                            [0]=>Array
                              (
                                [id] => 538
                                [name] => CPU 1998
                                [parent_id] => 53
                              )
                          )
                      [Intel]=>Array() // Keep this one for new CPU from Intel
                    )


        )

)
```

I have tried creating one more function to insert the brands into the parent levels, but my problem is, how can I put the children's CPU into their corresponding brands?

```
function brand(array $elements,$children){
  $branch = array();
  foreach($elements as $k=>$element){          
    /* if($element['brand'] == $children['brand']) not working **/
     $branch[$element['brand']] = $children;
  }
  return $branch;
}

function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
 $branch = array();

 foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
        $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
        if ($children) {
            $element['brands'] = brand($elements,$children);

        }
        $branch[] = $element;
    }
 }

 return $branch;
}
```

That gives me this result:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [brand] => Intel
                [id] => 53
                [name] => CPU 1978
                [parent_id] => 0
                [brands]=> Array
                        (
                          [Asus]=> Array
                               (
                                 [0] => Array
                                 (
                                   [brand]=> Asus
                                   [id] => 537
                                   [name] => CPU 1999
                                   [parent_id] => 53
                                 )
                                 [1]=>Array
                                  (
                                    [brand]=>HTC
                                    [id] => 538
                                    [name] => CPU 1998
                                    [parent_id] => 53
                                  )
                               )

                          [HTC] => Array
                              (
                                 [0] => Array
                                 (
                                   [brand]=> Asus
                                   [id] => 537
                                   [name] => CPU 1999
                                   [parent_id] => 53
                                 )
                                  [1]=>Array
                                  (
                                    [brand]=>HTC
                                    [id] => 538
                                    [name] => CPU 1998
                                    [parent_id] => 53
                                  )
                              )
                          [Intel]=>Array(
                              (
                                 [0] => Array
                                 (
                                   [brand]=> Asus
                                   [id] => 537
                                   [name] => CPU 1999
                                   [parent_id] => 53
                                 )
                                  [1]=>Array
                                  (
                                    [brand]=>HTC
                                    [id] => 538
                                    [name] => CPU 1998
                                    [parent_id] => 53
                                  )
                              )
                           )
                      )


            )

    )
```

Comment: Can you please share your very first array that you used for processing further. it will help to give the correct answer of your problem.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Check out my post. I have updated it with the array fetched from mysql for building hierarchy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RedGiant, the following function will take the output of your existing `buildTree()` method and recursively transform it in such a way that all `children` elements in the array tree will be replaced with `brands`:

```
function brand(array $elements)
{
    // Return early if parent has no children
    if (! array_key_exists('children', $elements)) {
        return $elements;
    }

    // Initialise local values
    $brands = array();

    // Transform children (recursively)
    foreach ((array) $elements['children'] as $child) {
        $brand = $child['brand'];
        unset($child['brand']);

        // Use call_user_func() and __function__ to prevent name dependency
        // within the function itself. If required, this can be replaced with:
        // $brands[$brand] = array(brand($child);
        $brands[$brand] = array(call_user_func(__function__, $child));
    }

    // Replace children with brands
    unset($elements['children']);
    $elements['brands'] = $brands;

    return $elements;
}
```

The function should be invoked via `array_map()`, ie:

```
$old_tree = buildTree($original_flat_array)
$new_tree = array_map('brand', buildTree($original_flat_array));
```

The advantage of this solution is that it preserves all of the existing array keys (apart from `children`, obviously). Thus, any key you may add to the original flat array in the future will be carried through into the new transformed array tree without the need for code modification.

Answer (score 2):

***Edit: My previous answer failed badly when there were multiple child elements for a brand. Below is a much more robust solution.***

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0)
{
    $branch = [];

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $element['brands'] = brand(buildTree($elements, $element['id']));

            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

function brand(array $elements)
{
    $branch = [];
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $branch[$element['brand']][] = [
            'id' => $element['id'],
            'name' => $element['name'],
            'parent_id' => $element['parent_id'],
        ];
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

This returns the following from the original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => Intel
            [id] => 53
            [name] => CPU 1978
            [parent_id] => 0
            [brands] => Array
                (
                    [Asus] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 537
                                    [name] => CPU 1999
                                    [parent_id] => 53
                                )
                        )
                    [HTC] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 538
                                    [name] => CPU 1998
                                    [parent_id] => 53
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```